# Cumulative constraint not working with variable size arrays of variables in Minizinc?

Tags: minizinc

I have a Constraint Programming model in Minizinc 2.7.5 (with Gecode 6.3.0) and I want to use the Cumulative constraint on a subset of variables.
It seems like the constraint does not work when the subset of variables can be of variable size.
Can someone help me ?

Here is the model (not working) :

```
% Data variables
enum tasks;
array[tasks] of int: D;

int: num_steps;
set of int: steps = 1..num_steps;

int: num_dimensional_groups;
array[1..num_dimensional_groups] of set of tasks: dimensional_groups;

% Decision variables
array[tasks] of var 1..num_steps+1: X;
array[tasks] of var 1..2*num_steps: Z;

array[1..num_dimensional_groups] of var int: N;
array[1..num_dimensional_groups] of var set of tasks: cumul_tasks;

% Constraints
include "globals.mzn";

constraint forall(t in tasks)(Z[t] = X[t] + D[t] - 1);

% Definition of a subset of tasks
constraint forall(i in 1..num_dimensional_groups)(
  cumul_tasks[i] = {t | t in (
    (tasks diff dimensional_groups[i]) union {arg_min([X[t] | t in dimensional_groups[i]])} union {arg_max([Z[t] | t in dimensional_groups[i]])} 
  )}
);

constraint forall(i in 1..num_dimensional_groups)(
  cumulative(
    [X[t]  | t in cumul_tasks[i]], 
    [D[t]  | t in cumul_tasks[i]], 
    [1     | t in cumul_tasks[i]], 
    N[i]
   )
);
```

Here is a sample data :

```
num_steps=25;

% Tasks
tasks = {T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10};

D = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1];

% Tasks grouped by dimension
num_dimensional_groups = 3;
dimensional_groups = [
  {T1, T2, T3},
  {T4, T5, T6, T7, T8},
  {T9, T10}
];
```

Here is the error message I get :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the `opt` version of cumulative is that a task might or might not be run, but that all tasks exists (or at least have some definition). This translates to that the start times might be `opt`, but the duration and resource consumption must be actual variables.

This works for your model al well. Instead of iterating over the `var set of tasks` for the duration and consumption, you instead iterate over the upper bound of the set. These are all the the possible tasks in the set.

```
constraint forall(i in 1..num_dimensional_groups)(
  let { set of tasks: all_tasks = to_enum(tasks, ub(cumul_tasks[i])); } in
  cumulative(
    [X[t]  | t in cumul_tasks[i]], 
    [D[t]  | t in all_tasks], 
    [1     | t in all_tasks], 
    N[i]
   )
);
```

Note that I had to add `to_enum` in the definition of `all_tasks`. This is because of a bug in the current definition of `ub` that erases the enum type. This will hopefully be resolved in the next version of MiniZinc.